# Add method for cloning class objects

Tags: ecmascript-6

I wish to be able to clone objects of my class. How should I implement the clone method for the class below?

```
export default class Foo {
    constructor(data) {
        this.name = data.firstName + " " + data.lastName 
        this.id = data.objectId
    }

    clone(s){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another instance of the class and copy over the properties:

```
clone() {
    return Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)), this);
//  or simply
//  return Object.assign(new this.constructor({}), this);
}
```

You might also pass the options so that the properties are initialised in the constructor as expected:

```
clone() {
    return new Foo({
        firstName: this.name.split(" ")[0],
        lastName: this.name.split(" ").slice(1).join(" "),
        objectId: this.id
    });
}
```

However, notice that creating multiple instances with the same (but supposedly unique) id might not be the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to clone from one instance of a class to another, you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
export default class Foo {
    constructor(data) {
        this.name = data.firstName + " " + data.lastName 
        this.id = data.objectId
    }

    clone(s) {
      // It's important to initalize using an empty object, so as to not cause errors
      let copy = new Foo({});
      Object.assign(copy, this);
      return copy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind this will fail dangerously if you happen to bind any methods in the class constructor since the bound methods would also be copied.

Comment: If you wanted to play it safe, could you `for` through the elements of `this`?